# PHP элементы одного массива в другой по ключу

Tags: php, массивы

Как можно реализовать данную задачу?
Цель - получить array3.
В первом массиве у каждого элемента содержится ID этого элемента.
Во втором массиве у неизвестного количества элементов содержатся ID, идентичные элементам из первого массива. 
Как можно сделать элементы второго массива вложенные в подходящие по ID элементы первого?

```
<?
    $array1 = array(
        [0] => array(
            'id' => 1
        ),
        [1] => array(
            'id' => 2
        ),
        [n] => array(
            'id' => n
        ),
    );
?>


<?
    $array2 = array(
        [0] => array(
            'target_id' => 1
        ),
        [1] => array(
            'target_id' => 2
        ),
        [2] => array(
            'target_id' => 1
        ),
        [3] => array(
            'target_id' => n
        ),
    );
?>


<?
    $array3 = array(
        [0] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'children' => array(
                [0] => array(
                    'target_id' => 1
                ),
                [1] => array(
                    'target_id' => 1
                )
            )
        ),

        [1] => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'children' => array(
                [0] => array(
                    'target_id' => 2
                )
            )
        ),

        [n] => array(
            'id' => n,
            'children' => array(
                [0] => array(
                    'target_id' => n
                )
            )
        ),
    );
?>
```

Comment: А по конкретнее? Более развернуто объясните то, чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: `$array3` - это как должно выглядеть?

Comment: Прошу прощения, что сразу не добавил описание. Приложил к задаче

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array1 = [
    ['id'=>1],
    ['id'=>2],
];
$array2 =[
    ['target_id' => 1],
    ['target_id' => 2],
    ['target_id' => 1]
];


$array3 = [];
foreach($array1 as $elem){
    $elem['children'] = array_filter($array2, function($item) use($elem){
        return $item['target_id']== $elem['id'];
    });
    $array3[] = $elem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = [['id' => 1], ['id' => 2], ['id' => 5]];
$arr2 = [['target_id' => 1], ['target_id' => 2], ['target_id' => 1], ['target_id' => 5]];

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
    $new[$value['target_id']][] = $value;
}

$x = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    return ['id' => $a['id'], 'children' => $b];
}, $arr1, $new);

print_r($x);
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот вариант тоже подходит.